# sax parsing in blackberry

Tags: parsing, blackberry, sax

I am trying to parse xml resource but I am not able to.

The xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <elencoanagrafiche trovati="7" errStatus="0">
        <anagrafica>
            <idAnagrafica>75</idAnagrafica>
            <nome><![CDATA[Alberto]]></nome>
            <cognome><![CDATA[Pippo]]></cognome>
            <email><![CDATA[aaa.bbb@ccc.it]]></email>
            <dataDiNascita><![CDATA[26/07/1478]]></dataDiNascita>
        </anagrafica>
        <anagrafica>
        .
        .
        </anagrafica>
    </elencoanagrafiche>
```

My sax parsing class:

```
package mypackage;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;

import net.rim.device.api.ui.Field;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.FieldChangeListener;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.UiApplication;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.ButtonField;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.Dialog;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.LabelField;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.RichTextField;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.HorizontalFieldManager;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.MainScreen;
import net.rim.device.api.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import net.rim.device.api.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;

import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

public class XMLSAXParser extends MainScreen {

    private ButtonField _bIndietro = null;
    private UiApplication _uiApp;
    LabelField lbLine = new LabelField("-------------");

    public XMLSAXParser() {

        //setup della pagina(layout, bottoni, text)
        add(new RichTextField(ConnectionClass.url));

        _bIndietro = new ButtonField("Indietro", Field.FIELD_HCENTER | ButtonField.CONSUME_CLICK);
        _bIndietro.setChangeListener(new FieldChangeListener() {
            public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {
                ConnectionClass.connect();
                _uiApp.popScreen(XMLSAXParser.this);
            }
        });

        add(_bIndietro);

        _uiApp = UiApplication.getUiApplication();

        try {

            SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();

            DefaultHandler handler = new DefaultHandler() {

                boolean bidAnagrafica, belencoanagrafiche = false;
                boolean bname, banagrafica = false;
                boolean bcognome = false;

                public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes)
                        throws SAXException {

                    System.out.println("Start Element :" + qName);

                    if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("elencoanagrafiche")) {
                        belencoanagrafiche = true;
                    }
                    if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("anagrafica")) {
                        banagrafica = true;                 
                    }
                    if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("idAnagrafica")) {
                        bidAnagrafica = true;
                    }
                    if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("nome")) {
                        bname = true;                       
                    }
                    if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("cognome")) {
                        bcognome = true;
                    }
                }

                public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {
                    System.out.println("End Element :" + qName);            
                }

                public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) throws SAXException {

                    if (belencoanagrafiche) {
                        LabelField lb = new LabelField("elencoanagrafiche : " + new String(ch, start, length));
                        HorizontalFieldManager sr = new HorizontalFieldManager();
                        sr.add(lb);
                        add(sr);
                        belencoanagrafiche = false;
                    }

                    if (banagrafica) {
                        LabelField lb = new LabelField("anagrafica : " + new String(ch, start, length));
                        HorizontalFieldManager sr = new HorizontalFieldManager();
                        sr.add(lb);
                        add(sr);
                        add(new LabelField("-----"));
                        banagrafica = false;
                    }

                    if (bidAnagrafica) {
                        LabelField lb = new LabelField("idAnagrafica : " + new String(ch, start, length));
                        HorizontalFieldManager sr = new HorizontalFieldManager();
                        sr.add(lb);
                        add(sr);
                        bidAnagrafica = false;
                    }

                    if (bname) {
                        LabelField lb = new LabelField("Nome :" + new String(ch, start, length));
                        HorizontalFieldManager sr = new HorizontalFieldManager();
                        sr.add(lb);
                        add(sr);
                        bname = false;
                    }

                    if (bcognome) {
                        LabelField lb = new LabelField("Cognome : " + new String(ch, start, length));
                        HorizontalFieldManager sr = new HorizontalFieldManager();
                        sr.add(lb);
                        add(sr);
                        bcognome = false;
                    }
                }

            };


            InputStream inputStream = ConnectionClass.httpConn.openInputStream();
            Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"UTF-8");

            InputSource is = new InputSource(reader);
            is.setEncoding("UTF-8");

            //InputStream inputStream = ConnectionClass.httpConn.openInputStream();

            saxParser.parse(inputStream, handler);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Dialog.alert("Exception Error: " + e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Now my problem is that I don't get any element values like name, cognome, email, etc. I just get the id identificators but I do not get the data within the . so my question is how do I get the data within the CDATA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess: the characters() method is called more than once, you get an empty string on the first call, and set the boolean flag to false.
You should use a StringBuffer on subsequent characters() invocation, like this:

```
private StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

...

public void characters(final char[] ch, final int start, final int length) throws SAXException
{
    buffer.append(new String(ch, start, length).trim());
}
```

And leave the processing to the endElement() method (clearing the buffer when done).